# jquery autocomplete from php vars

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
<?php require_once('Connections/root.php'); ?> 
<?php $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM performer"); ?>
```

```
<script> $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = ["<?php while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { echo $r['username']; } ?>"];
        $("#search_box").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

the script works but it displayes : User1User2User3

and i want it to display:

User1

User2

User3

How do i add a new line after every user and where do i add the line feed

if i make it like this

```
var availableTags = ["<?php while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { echo $r['username'] . " <br />"; } ?>"];
```

i get User1User2User3 and the br as a string

Comment: That is because your `availableTags` array only contains 1 string variable.

Comment: ok...then please explain how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, your `availableTags` array has only 1 string variable.
You need to push the string to the Array.

You can try this:

```
var availableTags = [];
<?php while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { ?>
    availableTags.push('<?php echo $r['username']; ?>');
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please accept this answer if this helped you solve your question.

Comment: This will break if `$r['username']` has a single quote it in

Answer (score 4):

Separate your PHP logic from your Javascript code. Up top, build a PHP array first:

```
$tags = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) { 
    $tags[] = $r['username'];
}
```

Then in your javascript, echo the array [JSON encoded](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($tags); ?>;
```

**Note:** You are using deprecated `mysql_*` functions and should switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: I upvoted, but please don't use the word `Obligatory` here, as I think the internet doesn't understand what that adjective really means..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Heh, what would you suggest? Are you saying I don't understand what it means?

Comment: Nope, not saying that at all, but sometimes we over complicate things and not everyone speaks english heh

Answer (score 0):

The generated js array is not what you expect it to be. With your code, you obtain

```
var availableTags = ["User1User2User3"];
```

whereas what you need is

```
var availableTags = ["User1", "User2", "User3"];
```

Yous should adapt your PHP code to generate the right JS.